# Cannot implement multiple inheritance with QObject

Tags: pyqt5, multiple-inheritance, python-3.12

Code snippet:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject
import sys

class ParentA:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.b = x + y

class Child(QObject, ParentA):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        QObject.__init__(self) # <- Error is thrown here
        z = x + 2
        ParentA.__init__(self, z, y)
        self.c = "Child specific value"
        print("end")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    Child(1,2)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Error message:

> Exception has occurred: TypeError
> ParentB.**init**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y'

Error thrown on first line of Child constructor

Using VS code on windows

When you replace QObject with a self-made class, the problem does not appear. Also if you do not call the QObject **init** function in the Child constructor, there is no problem, but I believe there is no reason why I should refrain from calling the QObject constructor.

Comment: It seems to be an implementation detail specific to PyQt. The same example does not raise an exception with PySide. For PyQt, if you change the definition to `class Child(ParentA, QObject)` the problem will go away. But really, you should be using `super` for cases like this. See the PyQt docs: [Support for Cooperative Multi-inheritance](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/multiinheritance.html).